# Get the current layout from an Appender in Logback?

Tags: java, logback

Consider the following basic configuration for logback:

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="ControlAppender" class="org.quackbot.ControlAppender">
        <pattern>%d{MM/dd/yyy hh:mm:ss a}  %-5p %c - </pattern>
    </appender>
</configuration>
```

How can I use that layout and format the line? A few different blog posts and mailing lists said that at one time AppenderBase had a getLayout() and setLayout() method, but they have sense been removed.

Reimplementing the getters and setters for the layout in my code don't work, it just returns null. `event.getFormattedMessage()` returns the original line, not the formatted one. I can't seem to find any other method that would format the message according to the layout.

Is there any way to format a message according to the pattern specified in the configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logback configuration just pieces together the elements that you specify. It does not make up components on its own. In the config file above, you have not specified a layout element and as such it won't get injected to your ControlAppender.

Since I don't know what ControlAppender does I can't suggest the most appropriate solution. However, you have at least two options:

1) Have ControlAppender accept a layout as a parameter. Your config file would look similar to:

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="ControlAppender" class="org.quackbot.ControlAppender">
        <layout class="class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout"">
          <pattern>%d{MM/dd/yyy hh:mm:ss a}  %-5p %c - </pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>
</configuration>
```

Logback would inject a PatternLayout instance into ControlAppender. You could then use the  PatternLayout instance to format events according the pattern of your choice.

2) If you are always going to use a PatternLayout, you could create it directly from the pattern. Your config file would look similar to:

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="ControlAppender" class="org.quackbot.ControlAppender">
      <pattern>%d{MM/dd/yyy hh:mm:ss a}  %-5p %c - </pattern>
    </appender>
</configuration>
```

You would need a setter method in ControlAppender, i.e. setPattern, to have the pattern injected into ControlAppender. Once you have the pattern, you could create a PatternLayout on your own. For example by invoking:

```
 PatternLayout pl = new PatternLayout();
 pl.setPattern(pattern);
 pl.setContext(context);
 pl.start();
```

Shout on the logback users list if you need further assistance.